# Display AVG on Left Join

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the average of Score field of StudentQuizReading, StudentQuizLanguage, and StudentQuizMath tables on the left join.

How can I do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
$query = "
SELECT s.StudentID
     , s.LastName
     , s.FirstName
     , s.MiddleName
     , s.Level
     , s.Adviser
     , r.Score
     , l.Score
     , m.Score 
  FROM Students s
  LEFT 
  JOIN StudentQuizReading r
    ON r.StudentID = s.StudentID
  LEFT 
  JOIN StudentQuizLanguage l
    ON l.StudentID = s.StudentID
  LEFT 
  JOIN StudentQuizMath m
    ON m.StudentID = s.StudentID
 WHERE s.StudentID = '".$_POST["StudentID"]."'
 ";
```

Details of tables: StudentQuizReading, StudentQuizLanguage, StudentQuizMath

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Field     | Type        | 
+-----------+-------------+
| StudentID | int(5)      |
| QuizNum   | varchar(10) | 
| Score     | int(2)      | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design. Consider whether it's the right approach having 3 tables holding essentially the same kind of information.

Comment: Also, note that the number in parentheses after `int` is almost meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `null` of `StudentID` in `LEFT` joined table column and can find the avg.

Check the query below.

```
$query = "SELECT
  Students.StudentID,
  Students.LastName,
  Students.FirstName,
  Students.MiddleName,
  Students.Level,
  Students.Adviser,
  FirstQuarterGrades.Reading,
  FirstQuarterGrades.Language,
  FirstQuarterGrades.Mathematics,
  (SUM(IF(StudentQuizReading.StudentID IS NULL, 0, StudentQuizReading.Score)) / SUM(IF(StudentQuizReading.StudentID IS NULL, 0, 1))) AS StudentQuizReadingAvg,
  (SUM(IF(StudentQuizLanguage.StudentID IS NULL, 0, StudentQuizLanguage.Score)) / SUM(IF(StudentQuizLanguage.StudentID IS NULL, 0, 1))) AS StudentQuizLanguageAvg,
  (SUM(IF(StudentQuizMath.StudentID IS NULL, 0, StudentQuizMath.Score)) / SUM(IF(StudentQuizMath.StudentID IS NULL, 0, 1))) AS StudentQuizMathAvg
FROM Students
  LEFT JOIN StudentQuizReading ON Students.StudentID = StudentQuizReading.StudentID
  LEFT JOIN StudentQuizLanguage ON Students.StudentID = StudentQuizLanguage.StudentID
  LEFT JOIN StudentQuizMath ON Students.StudentID = StudentQuizMath.StudentID
WHERE Students.StudentID = '".$_POST["StudentID"]."'";
```

Comment: The OP has changed the table alias.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @anon is that query worked? If so, you can accept the answer so that it would be helpful to others who have similar problem.